# Rotate a given matrix by K times

Tags: c

To rotate a matrix by `K` times means shifting the columns of the given `N*N` matrix to the right by `K` places.
For example, consider a `3*3` matrix, which has to be rotated.

Input:

```
n = 3;
k = 2;
```

Matrix before Rotation:

```
10  20  30
40  50  60
70  80  90
```

Expected output:

```
20  30  10
50  60  40
80  90  70
```

Actual output:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I don't know where am getting it wrong. Please sort it out. :(
Below is my attempt.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n,i,j,k,temp=0;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int arr[n][n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
      for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
         scanf("%d",&arr[i][j]);
       }
    }
    scanf("%d",&k);
  
    for(int l=1;l<=k;l++){
    temp=arr[i][0];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=1;j<n-1;j++){
            arr[i][j]=arr[i][j+1];
        }
    }
    arr[i][j]=temp;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            printf("%d",arr[i][j]);
        }
        
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey sam. You've included your expected output, but did not include what you're actually getting instead, or what you've tried to find the problem. People here will be much more likely to be able to help you if you can narrow down the problem space a little bit, and show your own effort in solving the problem.

Comment: what should be the rotated value if rotate by 2 ?

Comment: `temp=arr[i][0];` - have you thought about what is `i` at this point? Also, if you really meant `[0,0]` the following loop does not write to this location first but to `arr[0][1];`.

Comment: Yes ,temp should point to  [0,0] .If it points [0][1] then how shall I rewrite the code......

Comment: You have multiple definitions of `i` and `j`. To better understand my point, change `int n,i,j,k,temp=0;` into `int n,k,temp=0;` and pay attention to compiler warnings after building.

Comment: Your question seems to be a [homework question](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems). Are you allowed to use pointers?

Comment: yes we can use..

Comment: `arr[i][j]=temp;` What value do `i` and `j` have at this point, and why?

Comment: Please describe what makes your think that you are "getting it wrong".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The Solution

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int n = 0, k = 0;
    
    while(n > 100 || n <= 0)//to prevent absurd values. Adjust as required
    {
        printf ("Enter length of matrix: ");
        scanf ("%d", &n);
    }
    printf ("Enter shift times: ");
    scanf ("%d", &k);
    k = k % n;//get rid of excess shifts
    k = n - k;//convert shift direction (right to left)
    int arr[n][n];
    printf ("Enter elements of matrix:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            scanf ("%d", &arr[i][j]);//populates the matrix
        }
    }
    
    int temp[n][k];//for storing part of matrix while swapping
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
        {
            temp[i][j] = arr[i][j];//stores part of matrix
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = k; j < n; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j - k] = arr[i][j];//moves remaining part of matrix
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = n - k; j < n; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = temp[i][j - (n - k)];//places stored part in position
        }
    }
    
    printf ("The matrix:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf ("%d\t", arr[i][j]);//prints the matrix
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

## The explanation

Did you ever think what would happen if the value of `k` were greater than `i`?
The line `k = k % n` deals with it. It changes the number of right shifts to the minimun number of right shifts required.

The line `k = n - k` changes the number of right shifts to the equivalent number of left shifts. This is required as the our code left shifts the matrix by `k` columns.
*Why?* Because I wanted it to do so.

Note that the code following the statement `int temp[n][k];` is very similar to what we write to swap two variables using a third.

```
temp = a;
a = b;
b = temp;
```

Finally, we print our matrix.

### Note:

The program has been written in a way that is easy to read and  understand. It has not been optimized for performance.